# Java Printing a ticket

Tags: java, printing

I am trying to print a ticket on **Fujitsu fp-460** with this code

```
public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.translate((int)pf.getImageableY(),(int) pf.getImageableY());        
        g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 20));         
        g.drawString("Some Text", 00, 00);
        g.drawString("Some Text", 00, 20);
        g.drawString("Some Text", 00, 40);        
        g.drawString("Some Text", 00, 60);
        return PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
```

but the printed paper have some margin on left and right how to make it print it full page ?
Printer works fine when printing from other places

Comment: @SabirKhan for this snippet i really do not see the relevancy. If there are several similary named libraries, I agree. This is not vague at all. Besides this snippet will not compile as it is, so the imports make little difference...

Comment: what do you want more to know ?? 
my only problem is the paper width @SabirKan

Comment: Is is generally better to include a self contained example (see http://sscce.org/), so others can run your code as well (altough they problably won't have a similar printer, I doubt the problem is the printer)

Comment: no printer works fine other ways

Comment: What is the margin size with the code above, and what is the margin size otherwise? Maybe that could help us to trace your problem.

Comment: @SabirKhan the purpose of the snippet is for the understanding of the question. if you can understand it and solve it without the imports, it is less bloat, and thus not necessary. If you still disagree, create a topic in meta. I think that the [mcve] guidelines are along the same road as what i am saying...

Comment: Does "printing to pdf" with foxit reader or some other pdf printer give the same issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java printing: creating a PageFormat with minimum acceptable margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455268/java-printing-creating-a-pageformat-with-minimum-acceptable-margin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an expert in AWT printing, but based on the API I found this, give it a try:

```
pageFormat.getPaper().setSize(paperWidth, paperHeight);
pageFormat.getPaper().setImageableArea(iaX, iaY, iaWidth, iaHeight);
```

These should manipulate the paper size and your printable area.

Comment: what are the values of paperWidth,paperHeight,iaX,iaY,iaWidth,iHeight

Comment: You can get the current values from `pageFormat..getPaper().get...` getters, then you can try to play around the values. I think that you need the `setImageableArea`, you have the printing area rectangle defined by X/Y, Width/Height parameters.

Answer (score 0):

### Physical limitation

This printer (and most printers in general) has a maximum print width that is smaller than the page, so you will never be able to print it [full bleed](https://www.mgxcopy.com/blog/san-diego-printing/2014/04/30/full-bleed-printing-need/)

See here: https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/164/fp-460-2368.pdf

Revelant section:

[image]

### Software limitation

As it is not clear how you get your `PageFormat`, it is hard to tell what you did wrong. Maybe check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10484729/461499

Comment: No but its' printing less than the maximum print width I tried to print outside my code and it works fine

Comment: Please update your question as this is not clear from your problem statement. Maybe you can include some pictures as well?

Comment: right now I can't provide photos
I just want to know how to set the paper to the maximum width